# Hibernate exception : cannot be cast to [B

Tags: java, hibernate

I am receiving below exception while i am trying to load data from database using hibernate

```
com.tpt.tradecapture.common.exception.TradeEntryRuntimeException: com.tpt.tradecapture.gateway.tradecontentdefination.persistable.DataDictionaryPersistable cannot be cast to [B 
    at com.tpt.tradecapture.ion.formlayouts.FormLayoutsTalkFunction.fetchFormLayoutDelegate(FormLayoutsTalkFunction.java:91)
    at com.tpt.tradecapture.ion.formlayouts.FormLayoutsTalkFunction.lambda$getFormLayout$1(FormLayoutsTalkFunction.java:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at com.iontrading.isf.executors.impl.monitoring.e.run(MonitoredRunnable.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Data Dictionary Persistable class used with JPA, Any help would be appreciated

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
@KeepAll
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
public class DataDictionaryPersistable extends DataPersistable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 998645843751342487L;

  private byte[] uuid;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "UUID")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public byte[] getUuid() {
    return this.uuid;
  }

  public void setUuid(final byte[] uuid) {
    this.uuid = uuid;
  }

  @Column(name = "ID")
  public String getId() {
    return this.getStringDataValue("ID");
  }

  public void setId(final String id) {
    this.setDataValue("ID", id);
  }

  @Column(name = "LABEL")
  public String getLabel() {
    return this.getStringDataValue("LABEL");
  }

  public void setLabel(final String label) {
    this.setDataValue("LABEL", label);
  }

  @Column(name = "TYPE")
  public String getType() {
    return this.getStringDataValue("TYPE");
  }

  public void setType(final String type) {
    this.setDataValue("TYPE", type);
  }
}
```

TABLE DDl SCRIPT for creating above table, please help if anyone knows about this error

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(
    UUID      RAW(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    ID        VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    LABEL   VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
    TYPE      VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: "`DataDictionaryPersistable cannot be cast to [B`" means you're trying to cast a `DataDictionaryPersistable` to a `byte[]`. It can't be a `byte[]`, because `byte[]` is `final`.

Comment: If i change my byte array to string it works fine but with byte array it is not working...i am not explicitly casting my persistable to byte array

Comment: You use oracle database, don't you? Please look at `hibernate.dialect.oracle.prefer_long_raw` option [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#_jdbc_related_options)

Comment: i am using raw not long raw...i tried setting this property to true but it did not worked out

Comment: @ShivamMalvia What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: And could you please provide the full stack trace of your exception. I can not see any mentions of hibernate in your stack trace.